# Can't save data from UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I tried to program a sign up view controller and use a `UIPickerView` for country choice. The issue is that when I tried to pass the picker country to Parse to save the input, Xcode give me an error. Why Xcode can't allow me to use the selected data to Parse? The error is in the last line.

Any help guys?

```
@IBOutlet var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var fullnameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var phonenumberTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var countryPicker: UIPickerView!

let countryData: [String] = ["Saudi Arabia", "Turkey"]

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return countryData.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let countrySelect = countryData[row]
    print(countrySelect)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    countryPicker.dataSource = self
    countryPicker.delegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func signUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Declare user object
    let newUser = PFUser()

    let fullName = fullnameTextField.text!
    let username = usernameTextField.text!
    let email:String = emailTextField.text!
    let password:String = passwordTextField.text!
    let phoneNumber:Int? = Int(phonenumberTextField.text!)

    // Passing arguments
    newUser.username = username
    newUser["fullName"] = fullName
    newUser.email = email
    newUser.password = password
    newUser["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber! as Int
    newUser["country"] = countryData [row]
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error is in the last line of the code "use of unresolved identifier 'row'"

Comment: @rmaddy The error is in the last line of the code "use of unresolved identifier 'row'"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893783/cant-save-data-to-parse#comment69028465_40893783) that the error is "unresolved identifier row":

You are never declaring a variable named `row`, yet you're using it. You can either replace the use of this undefined variable with the correct array index that will give you the country from the `countryData` variable OR you make sure that row is actually declared and accessible in your function.

Comment: So since I haven't declare row, I tried to use only countryData to store in parse. The problem is that it' store the whole array not one specific choice. So, tell me how to fix this issue so I can able to store one picker choice to parse ?

Comment: Well you need to map whatever choice the user made to an array index of `countryData`, for example, if the selection was Saudi Arabia, you would use `countryData[0]`, if it was Turkey you would use `countryData[1]`.

Comment: In addition to that, you can read about Arrays in Swift and how to use them here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107